# Can I have more than one connection in databricks-connect?

Tags: databricks, miniconda, databricks-connect

I have setup on my PC a miniconda python environment where I have installed the databricks-connect package and configured the tool with databricks-connect configure to connect to a databricks instance I want to use when developing code in the US.

I have a need to connect to a different a different databricks instance for developing code in the EU and I thought I could do this by setting up a different miniconda environment and installing databricks-connect in that environment and setting the configuration in that environment to point to the new databricks instance.

Alas, this did not work.  When I look at databricks-connect configure in either miniconda environment, I see the same configuration in both which is the configuration I last configured.

My question therefore is: Is there a way to have multiple databricks-connect connections at the same time and toggle between the two without having to reconfigure each time?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Right now, databricks-connect relies on the central configuration file, and this causes problems. There are two approaches to workaround that:

1. Use environment variables as described in the [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-connect.html#step-2-configure-connection-properties), but they should be set somehow, plus you need to have different python environments for different versions of databricks-connect
2. Specify parameters as spark configuration (see in the same documentation)
3. For each DB cluster, do following:

- separate python environment with name `<name>` & activate it
- install databricks-connect into it
- configure databricks-connect
- move `~/.databricks-connect` into `~/.databricks-connect-<name>`
- write wrapper script, that will activate python environment & symlink `~/.databricks-connect-<name>` into `~/.databricks-connect` (I [have such script for Zsh](https://gist.github.com/alexott/8214af9b72c9818d45d56f05f8641a18), it could be too long to paste it here.)